# Embedding google search data

Tags: api, web-applications, embed

I want to embed the no. of covid 19 cases of my country in my website, is there any way I can grab the data that google updates instead of manually updating every day

(ps: I am new to web development so any kind of help would be appreciated)
thanks in advance

Comment: Help us to help you! At least provide a link to the resource you want to embed.

Comment: https://ibb.co/QjPXSDF
I want to embed this info so that it updates automatically when google updates it in their search results